# Restoring database on SQL Server went wrong

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, database-restore

Let's say I have database named `db1` on SQL Server. I have daily backup, and I wanted to restore month old backup to new database, so I can recover just some info.

I created database `db2`, and tried to restore the `db1` backup to new and empty `db2` database.

I got message that backup I selected does not contain db2 backup **and it started to restore db1 itself!!!**

So now, for quite some time, next to `db1` there is message (restoring...)

How can I stop restoring db, I didn't wanted to restore db1 at first place, and that's why I choose to restore backup to db2 destination.

Is there any chance I still have today's db, not this one month old?

I still can't open `db1` to see what I have there, because it's not accessible.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you do log backups?

Comment: your database will most like come back online when you type: restore database [db1] WITH RECOVERY. However, that will probably be the 1 month old version. You mentioned in your first sentence that you make a daily ful backup, can't you take todays or yesterdays backup and restore that to DB1? At least you lost just a day's worth of day instead of 30 days....

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I am sure you are using GUI and you were not carful in that even. Please use query over GUI for max work.

Now your issue, I am not sure if you already fix but as  no reply on web

1. Now you lost your database, its of no use. So find a latest backup and restore db1 (you can use point in time recovery if you have t-log backups)
2. Restore db2 with 30 days old backup by query , use move option in restore or create new empty database first and then restore same with replace option.